# Heads Up Display Helmet With arduino

Tags: arduino-uno

I want to make a HUD Helmet similar to the one shown in Ironman movies. Please suggest me some links and parts needed for this type of project

Comment: Someone mentioned below and I think you should think about your goal (a helmet display) vs. your approach (an Ironman-styled helmet display). It is quite easy to do a helmet mounted display - VR being one. it is another story to an Ironman styled helmet display. If the latter is important to you, you may need to wait sometime.

Answer (score 3):

There is a fairly inexpensive solution, but it's not Arduino based.

All you need is:

- the [Google Cardboard sdk](https://www.google.com/get/cardboard/)
- a fairly modern and powerful Android phone (I have a OnePlusOne and it works well with Cardboard apps) - assuming you already own something similar, this is where the big saving happens :-)
- a compatible head unit: there are [many](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xgoogle%20cardboard.TRS0&_nkw=google%20cardboard&_sacat=0) available on ebay (on some you might have to drill a hole where the camera of the phone is located.) price got from about $5 to $25
- some high level programming skills to write your augmented reality application, but there's no way around it :-) - you might even find some demo on the net.

Here the basic of the solution I'm proposing is to take the video stream from the front camera on the phone, use the CardBoard API to create a view for each eye (yes, you will loose stereoscopy, since each eye will see the same image from the camera) and overlay it with whatever info you would like to show. The simpler case could be a compass, where you show N-W-S-E at the top of the field of view. Or you could even add a map, like in a FPS :-)

The part where the arduino might come useful is if you want to create some (bluetooth, for example) sensor and/or controller (using the usb port from the phone requires both a phone with HW that supports host mode and a rooted device).

Answer (score 1):

You will need Electroluminescent Transparent display, something like [this display from Beneq](https://beneq.com/en/displays/products/tasel)

But these displays are segmented displays...The problem with these displays  is these displays are very expensive :(
other problem is Focusing the display, You need to keep the display at your Focal distance..

Good thing is : You can use "CUSTOM ARDUINO" board to control this display, "IF" size is consideration :)

Happy Learning..

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  You can't even simulate it or even begin to approach that style of display.

Try it.  Print something out then hold it in front of your face the distance the visor is away from you.  Now try and focus on it.  You can't.  The human eyes are unable to focus that closely.

You would need to focus the vision through lenses (which is what VR headsets do) or directly project through prisms and lenses into the eye (which is what Google Glass does) in order for you to be able to see the images you generate.

You could do it if you required the user to wear special glasses to focus their vision, however they then wouldn't be able to focus on anything else much and would keep walking into things and tripping over their own feet.  The rest of the world would just be a complete blur.

The whole depiction of those kind of HUD displays are impractical.  In military HUD systems the image is either fed via a single eyepiece (and it takes lots of practice and brain training to get the brain to superimpose the two images), or it's projected on to the cockpit window.  The only way it could be done as they depict it would be to directly project the images into both eyes (to create a 3D effect) superimposing it over the natural light entering the eyes.  That would then of course mean that it would be invisible to anyone except the user, so still wouldn't be quite the same.

Comment: See my answer. Nowadays even VR and AR are getting quite cheap :-)

Comment: @IgorStoppa Do you know what the Iron man HUD is like? It's not a vr headset. There is no headset. It's nothing like Google cardboard or occulus rift or anything like that. A vr headset is not what the op is asking for.

Comment: Did you read my answer before writing the comment above? I described an _augmented_ reality contraption, not a VR headset. Which is precisely what can be done, as I described, with Cardboard, since there is a camera on the other side of the phone. The fact that in the movie the HUD is allegedly done with a projector is irrelevant, for the purpose of creating an augmented reality experience. At least I have proposed a plausible solution.

Comment: What you are describing is a VR headset that happens to have a camera. That's not AR, for that you need something like Glass . It's a completely different concept. If the OP wanted a VR headset, with or withoutvavcanera, he wouldn't be asking for an iron man hud.

Comment: Nope, you are just yet another victim of marketing campaigns. See the definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality. It's _exactly_ what I described. The key point is that you show to the user a live stream of a camera with a feed from (roughly) the same perspective as the real eyes. And then overlay it with additional info. So a VR device is perfectly ok, as long as it shows as base image a live feed from the user's perspective, rather than a fully synthesized world.

Comment: It still, whatever your chosen definition, isn't even close to the Iron man HUD the OP is asking about.

Comment: Matter of opinion. Btw, any sane design of a weaponized AR a-la-IronMan would do just this: use a slab of metal with a camera on the outer side and a display/projector on the inner side, rather than ALON for see-through, like HoloLens. The ALON can be used to protect the camera. So I think this is really close to what the OP was asking. But I'll let him decide.

Comment: > You can't. that's a little presumptive.

Comment: @dannyf Science Fiction is called that for a reason. With current technology it's impossible to project onto glass an inch away from an eyeball and be able to focus on it. So *you can't* is not presumptive, it's correct.

Comment: @Majenko This answer is categorically wrong. I'm sorry to sound harsh, but your last comment was in Jul of '17 at which point many examples where available to prove the concept is possible if you were to search for it. You should remove this or change it

Comment: @JSON I'd love to see one. I still say what the op asks for is impossible.

Comment: @Majenko - https://hackaday.com/2018/03/25/iron-man-mask-with-a-hud/ . Not the best, but at least proves it's possible

Comment: A poor man's Google glass. Have you seen the iron man HUD? It's nothing like that. Completely different. And impossible. Still, not a bad attempt at making something light up within the field of vision.

Comment: @Majenko I think your taking the OP's question too literally although a true reproduction would definitely be out of the question to an amateur. Since people who develop flying weapons systems aren't likely to frequent this Q/A I'm assuming the OP and others with interest are likely looking for something simpler than what your imagining ;)

Comment: You would be amazed at the preposterous things people that come here think they can do with an Arduino. Very often you just have to tell them no, and to get realistic.

Comment: From the film i think is pretty clear all of those effect is what Stark perceive, so a AR or a VR is exactly what he experience (AR advantage is that you have 0 latency on the outside image and your eyes has better contrast than any camera). He probably have VR and those effect are painted in the 3d space (the first time he put the mask, you can see the system does a full 3d scan of the room), so you can get basic result with a VR + camera + deep sensor (some smartphone). DJI has a game like this for its drone! (they use stereo camera for deep)

Answer (score 0):

Luckily the concept of an Ironman helmet has more options then one would think and can be broken down as if any form of helmet. First theres the question of dimensions and proportion - this has more options than I realized since the Ironman helmet has undergone many transformations over more than 50 years both in print and film. An image search of "Ironman mask" and "Ironman comic" shows that there are a lot of options to choose from. Additionally I haven't found a consensus to exactly how Ironman was able to see outside the helmet which leaves your options open as well.

The "Ironman Mask" has what some could argue are two covered openings for the user to look through. Call them windows, eye holes - what ever - but they are openings to allow the user a direct field of vision through the helmet. If this is the case you are asking for a system that projects an overlay of some type into the users natural line of sight. Others could argue that these "eyes" on the outside of the mask are just for looks and that the users vision is completely enclosed in the helmet and that their entire view of the outside world is somehow projected into their view within the helmet.

If we're speaking of the first case, an Arduino can be used for a simple head mounted display (there are multiple examples if you Google it - include terms "glass", "hmd", and "hud") but Uno and other atmel based Arduinos are limited to simple 8 bit animations and text, nothing truly impressive or emersive. You will also have the issue of image correction in cases where your trying to create a large overlay - the viewable image will warp and fade since not projected onto surface strait on. Lenses can be used to correct but this is costly and not realistic for most diy/makers which only leaves software based solutions which Uno cannot handle running. It is possible however with other boards like the pi zero which is comparable in size and price and has enough power for higher resolution graphics and image correction. Note this approach will still require a single lens for focusing the projected image, but these are basic and cheap lenses as opposed to prisms or multi-lens solutions.

The second case would functionally be more like a VR headset and could be a challenge with some designs of Ironman helmets due to limited space within the helmet. If willing to stretch the proportion of the helmet a generic low definition version could be created using cheap lenses and at least two unos. it will require at least one FPV camera module and two display modules as well as whatever sensors you would be using. this would be more in line with Igor Stoppa's answer.